# Authenticating as object owner to edit remote object permissions

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, authentication, windows-authentication

I have a Windows 7 machine, and a remote folder I am trying to change advanced permissions on. I'm the Administrator account on the local machine, and the remote folder is owned by a remote user that I have the credentials for.

I can't change the permissions on the object since my local account is not the owner. I don't want to change the owner of the object, since that causes a number of other issues.

Given that I have the credentials of the remote user, is there a way that I can authenticate as that user in the context of setting permissions, so that I can modify them?

I'm actually not entirely sure why I can't modify them, as the remote credentials are stored in the Credential Manager and I'm already authenticated (otherwise I wouldn't be able to access the remote filesystem at all). It seems like the permissions editor is in my local user context, though.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

There:

- ffloyd\Administrator is my local machine account
- SEAGATE-001\jason is the remote account I'd like to authenticate as (Seagate-001\jason\ is a similarly named folder; in case there's any confusion)
- SEAGATE-001\Administrators is a remote group (which \jason is a member of)
- I have credentials for all users and administrators on Seagate-001.

And my goal is to change permissions on this P73 folder without having to change its owner.

Comment: Have you considered taking ownership of the folder, assigning the your current user as the owner, then modifying the ACL to include whatever additional users should have access.  Once you have completed that operation set the owner back to the original owner? You won't be able to authenticate as the actual owner since it's NOT a Windows 7 user.  I am guessing this is an unspecified Seagate NAS/RAID HDD?

Answer (score 0):

Use `runas` to start a process in a new auth context:

```
runas /netonly /u:SEAGATE-001\jason cmd
```

In that new window, use `icacls` to change file permissions:

```
icacls \\Seagate-001\jason\P73 /grant Whoever:(OI)(CI)M
```

Note that in Windows/NTFS, the owner only gets implicit rights to *write* a new ACL, but not necessarily to *read* the existing ACL.